# Change background position div when input is focus

Tags: css, html, input, background, focus

I'm building form with images like a label...

I have:

```
DIV.icon-phone {
    width: 22px
    height: 22px
    background: url('icon-set.png') no-repeat 22px 66px;
}

INPUT.pool-phone {
    border:1px solid #666;
}
```

I would something like this:
if INPUT.pool-phone:focus change DIV.icon-phone background-position to: 44px 66px

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to alter some css property of an element when another element is modified, you need to have specific structures..

For your example, the `input` element must share the same immediate parent as the `div` and also be before it in the hierarchy.

In this case you can use the [`~` General sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) to target it

```
.pool-phone:focus ~ .icon-phone{
   background-position:...
}
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fx5Uy/

---

otherwise you can use javascript and bind to the `onfocus` event..

Answer (score 1):

you could write a javascript function to take care of that for you.

```
[the input button].onfocus = function changeBg () { [thediv].style.background="[whatever you want]" };
[the input button].onblur = function resetBg () { [thediv].style.background="[whatever you want]" };
```

Gaby posted a pure css version which is preferable (at least to me).

Comment: ok, but i have 8 divs with pools and this is big code size.
can i use somethig like: "+" or "<" sign with CSS only?!